# Trying to create an if statement after the while loop or something to do something else if the result is empty. Is this possible?

Tags: php, if-statement, is-empty

Trying to create an if statement after the while loop to do something else if the result is empty. Is this possible? I want to show different buttons if the result is empty.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tbody>
<form action = "create.php" method="POST">
<tr><td><input type="text" name="term" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"       style="border: 0px solid #000000;" readonly></td>
<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Create</button> </td>
</form>
</tr><td><button type="back" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="location.href='index.php'" >Back</button> </td>
<td></td>
</form><tr>
</tr>
</tbody>

<?php
};
?>
```

Comment: `if(empty($result))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row_count == 0){
?>
    <tbody>
    <form action = "create.php" method="POST">
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="term" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"       style="border: 0px solid #000000;" readonly></td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Create</button> </td>
    </form>
    </tr><td><button type="back" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="location.href='index.php'" >Back</button> </td>
    <td></td>
    </form><tr>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
<?php
}
else
{
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


    //Do your action



    ?>

    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there any way I could swap the code around and have the result checked first before the $row_count==0? As I am decrypting something but the file finds 0 rows first?

Answer (score 1):

Before your `while` loop, you can see if there are results with [`mysqli_num_rows($result)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Example :

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //If results
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //Your html
    }
}else{
    //If no results
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Couldn't get the HTML working in it so used the one above as it was easier. Thanks for the help though!